# Seekbar is not progressing

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I need to create a mediaplayer on click of a list item.It is created.It is playing,pausing,stopping without any disturbances.My problem is with the seekbar.It is moving only when i touch.At the start of the playing the audio file itself should progress.I have carefully watched through every part of the code.But not able to track the issue.
Thanks in advance.
    package com.pdev.activities;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RecordingActivity2 extends Activity  
 {

    ListView listView;
    VehicleAdapter myadapter;
    ArrayList<String> arr_cars = new ArrayList<String>();
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Utilities ut;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    ImageButton play,stop,close;
    TextView cd;
    SeekBar slider;
    Dialog dialog;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_example);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainList);
        ArrayList<Bitmap> arr_bitmaps1 = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(5);
        arr_bitmaps1.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.source));
        arr_bitmaps1.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.source));
        arr_bitmaps1.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.source));
        arr_bitmaps1.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.source));
        arr_bitmaps1.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.source));
        ArrayList<Bitmap> arr_bitmaps2 = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(5);
        arr_bitmaps2.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.vol));
        arr_bitmaps2.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.vol));
        arr_bitmaps2.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.vol));
        arr_bitmaps2.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.vol));
        arr_bitmaps2.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.vol));
        ArrayList<Bitmap> arr_bitmaps3 = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(5);
        arr_bitmaps3.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.timer));
        arr_bitmaps3.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.timer));
        arr_bitmaps3.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.timer));
        arr_bitmaps3.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.timer));
        arr_bitmaps3.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.timer));
        arr_cars.add("Example1");
        arr_cars.add("Example2");
        arr_cars.add("Example3");
        arr_cars.add("Example4");
        arr_cars.add("Example5");

        myadapter = new VehicleAdapter(RecordingActivity2.this, arr_bitmaps1,arr_bitmaps2,arr_bitmaps3, arr_cars);

        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        listView.addHeaderView(header);

        listView.setSelector( R.drawable.list_selector);

        listView.setAdapter(myadapter);

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, final int pos, long id) 
            { 
             Object listItem = listView.getItemAtPosition(pos);
             Toast.makeText(RecordingActivity2 .this, "The number of the long clicked item is " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordingActivity2.this);
             alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Playing");

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

                return true; //false will also trigger OnItemClick!
            } 
       });
    }


    public class VehicleAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        public String title[];
        public String description[];
        ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_name = new ArrayList<String>();
        public Activity context;
        ArrayList<Bitmap> image1Id,image2Id,image3Id; 

        public LayoutInflater inflater;


        public VehicleAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Bitmap> arr_bitmaps1,ArrayList<Bitmap> arrbitmaps2,ArrayList<Bitmap> arrbitmaps3, ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_name) {
            super();

            this.image1Id = arr_bitmaps1;
            this.image2Id = arrbitmaps2;
            this.image3Id = arrbitmaps3;
            this.context = context;
            this.arr_calllog_name = arr_calllog_name;

            this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImage1Id() {
            return image1Id;
        }

        public void setImage1Id(ArrayList<Bitmap> image1Id) {
            this.image1Id = image1Id;
        }

        public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImage2Id() {
            return image2Id;
        }

        public void setImage2Id(ArrayList<Bitmap> image2Id) {
            this.image2Id = image2Id;
        }

        public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImage3Id() {
            return image3Id;
        }

        public void setImage3Id(ArrayList<Bitmap> image3Id) {
            this.image3Id = image3Id;
        }





        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arr_calllog_name.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public class ViewHolder
        {
            ImageView source,play,timer;
            TextView txtName;
            Button btn;
            RelativeLayout row;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                holder.source = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                holder.play = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                holder.timer = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                //holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                holder.row = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lineItem);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

            holder.source.setImageBitmap(getImage1Id().get(position));
            holder.play.setImageBitmap(getImage2Id().get(position));
            holder.timer.setImageBitmap(getImage3Id().get(position));
            holder.txtName.setText(arr_calllog_name.get(position));
            holder.source.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Source",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog = new Dialog(RecordingActivity2.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Source File");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
                ImageButton im = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.closebutton);
                im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();                       
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                }
            });


            holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Playing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(RecordingActivity2.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
                play = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.play);
                stop = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.stop);
                close = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
                cd =(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.duration);
                slider = (SeekBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.seeker);
                ut = new Utilities();
                slider.setProgress(0);
                slider.setMax(100);
                slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress,
                            boolean arg2) {
                        //Toast.makeText(RecordingActivity2.this, "Seekbar Value : " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        //Toast.makeText(RecordingActivity2.this, "Started Tracking Seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        //Toast.makeText(RecordingActivity2.this, "Started Tracking Seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                        int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                        int currentPosition = ut.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(),
                                totalDuration);

                        // forward or backward to certain seconds
                        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

                        // update timer progress again
                        updateProgressBar();
                    }





                    });

                if(holder.txtName.getText().equals("Example1")){
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.aperture);    
                    Log.d("Check1",holder.txtName.getText().toString());
                       dialog.setTitle("Example1");
                  }
                else if(holder.txtName.getText().equals("Example2")){
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.coffee); 
                    Log.d("Check2",holder.txtName.getText().toString());
                    dialog.setTitle("Example2");    
                    }
                else if(holder.txtName.getText().equals("Example3")){
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.harperactive);
                    Log.d("Check3",holder.txtName.getText().toString());
                    dialog.setTitle("Example3");    
                    }
                else if(holder.txtName.getText().equals("Example4")){
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.nightmares);
                        Log.d("Check4",holder.txtName.getText().toString());
                        dialog.setTitle("Example4");    
                    }
                else{
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pianomeditation);    
                        Log.d("Check5",holder.txtName.getText().toString());
                        dialog.setTitle("Example5");    
                }

                play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                            if (mp != null) {
                                mp.pause();
                                // Changing button image to play button
                                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_play);

                            }
                        } else {
                            // Resume song
                            if (mp != null) {
                                mp.start();
                                // Changing button image to pause button
                                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_pause);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                );

                stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      dialog.dismiss();
                      mp.stop();
                    }
                });
                close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        mp.stop();

                    }
                 });

                dialog.show();
                }
                public void updateProgressBar() {
                    handler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
                }
                private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

                        // Displaying time completed playing
                        cd.setText(""
                                + ut.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

                        // Updating progress bar
                        int progress = (int) (ut.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration,
                                totalDuration));
                        // Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
                        slider.setProgress(progress);

                        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                    }
                };
            });


            holder.timer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                });

            holder.row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Selected: "+ holder.txtName.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return convertView;



        }

    }}
```

Comment: Are you sure that getProgressPercentage() method is correct?

Comment: getProgressPercentage() is not used in my code

Comment: Here it is: `int progress = (int) (ut.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration,
totalDuration));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atlast i found the answer.

```
package com.pdev.activities;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RecordingActivity2 extends Activity  
 {

    ListView listView;
    VehicleAdapter myadapter;
    ArrayList<String> arr_cars = new ArrayList<String>();
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Utilities ut;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    ImageButton play,stop,close;
    TextView cd;
    SeekBar slider;
    Dialog dialog;
    int currentPosition = 0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_example);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainList);
        ArrayList<Bitmap> arr_bitmaps1 = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(5);
        arr_bitmaps1.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.source));
        arr_bitmaps1.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.source));
        arr_bitmaps1.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.source));
        arr_bitmaps1.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.source));
        arr_bitmaps1.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.source));
        ArrayList<Bitmap> arr_bitmaps2 = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(5);
        arr_bitmaps2.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.vol));
        arr_bitmaps2.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.vol));
        arr_bitmaps2.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.vol));
        arr_bitmaps2.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.vol));
        arr_bitmaps2.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.vol));
        ArrayList<Bitmap> arr_bitmaps3 = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(5);
        arr_bitmaps3.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.timer));
        arr_bitmaps3.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.timer));
        arr_bitmaps3.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.timer));
        arr_bitmaps3.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.timer));
        arr_bitmaps3.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.timer));
        arr_cars.add("Example1");
        arr_cars.add("Example2");
        arr_cars.add("Example3");
        arr_cars.add("Example4");
        arr_cars.add("Example5");

        myadapter = new VehicleAdapter(RecordingActivity2.this, arr_bitmaps1,arr_bitmaps2,arr_bitmaps3, arr_cars);

        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        listView.addHeaderView(header);

        listView.setSelector( R.drawable.list_selector);

        listView.setAdapter(myadapter);

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, final int pos, long id) 
            { 
             Object listItem = listView.getItemAtPosition(pos);
             Toast.makeText(RecordingActivity2 .this, "The number of the long clicked item is " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordingActivity2.this);
             alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Playing");

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

                return true; //false will also trigger OnItemClick!
            } 
       });
    }


    public class VehicleAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        public String title[];
        public String description[];
        ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_name = new ArrayList<String>();
        public Activity context;
        ArrayList<Bitmap> image1Id,image2Id,image3Id; 

        public LayoutInflater inflater;


        public VehicleAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Bitmap> arr_bitmaps1,ArrayList<Bitmap> arrbitmaps2,ArrayList<Bitmap> arrbitmaps3, ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_name) {
            super();

            this.image1Id = arr_bitmaps1;
            this.image2Id = arrbitmaps2;
            this.image3Id = arrbitmaps3;
            this.context = context;
            this.arr_calllog_name = arr_calllog_name;

            this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImage1Id() {
            return image1Id;
        }

        public void setImage1Id(ArrayList<Bitmap> image1Id) {
            this.image1Id = image1Id;
        }

        public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImage2Id() {
            return image2Id;
        }

        public void setImage2Id(ArrayList<Bitmap> image2Id) {
            this.image2Id = image2Id;
        }

        public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImage3Id() {
            return image3Id;
        }

        public void setImage3Id(ArrayList<Bitmap> image3Id) {
            this.image3Id = image3Id;
        }





        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arr_calllog_name.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public class ViewHolder
        {
            ImageView source,play,timer;
            TextView txtName;
            Button btn;
            RelativeLayout row;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                holder.source = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                holder.play = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                holder.timer = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                //holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                holder.row = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lineItem);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

            holder.source.setImageBitmap(getImage1Id().get(position));
            holder.play.setImageBitmap(getImage2Id().get(position));
            holder.timer.setImageBitmap(getImage3Id().get(position));
            holder.txtName.setText(arr_calllog_name.get(position));
            holder.source.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Source",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog = new Dialog(RecordingActivity2.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Source File");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
                ImageButton im = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.closebutton);
                im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();                       
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                }
            });


            holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Playing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(RecordingActivity2.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
                play = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.play);
                stop = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.stop);
                close = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
                cd =(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.duration);
                slider = (SeekBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.seeker);
                ut = new Utilities();
                slider.setProgress(0);
                slider.setMax(100); 
                slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress,
                            boolean arg2) {
                        //Toast.makeText(RecordingActivity2.this, "Seekbar Value : " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        //Toast.makeText(RecordingActivity2.this, "Started Tracking Seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        //Toast.makeText(RecordingActivity2.this, "Started Tracking Seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                        int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                        currentPosition = ut.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(),
                                totalDuration);

                        // forward or backward to certain seconds
                        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

                        // update timer progress again
                        updateProgressBar();
                    }





                    });






                if(holder.txtName.getText().equals("Example1")){
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.aperture);    
                    Log.d("Check1",holder.txtName.getText().toString());
                       dialog.setTitle("Example1");
                  }
                else if(holder.txtName.getText().equals("Example2")){
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.coffee); 
                    Log.d("Check2",holder.txtName.getText().toString());
                    dialog.setTitle("Example2");    
                    }
                else if(holder.txtName.getText().equals("Example3")){
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.harperactive);
                    Log.d("Check3",holder.txtName.getText().toString());
                    dialog.setTitle("Example3");    
                    }
                else if(holder.txtName.getText().equals("Example4")){
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.nightmares);
                        Log.d("Check4",holder.txtName.getText().toString());
                        dialog.setTitle("Example4");    
                    }
                else{
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pianomeditation);    
                        Log.d("Check5",holder.txtName.getText().toString());
                        dialog.setTitle("Example5");    
                }

                play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                            if (mp != null) {
                                mp.pause();
                                // Changing button image to play button
                                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_play);
                                Log.d("CurrentPosition1",""+currentPosition);
                                //slider.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
                                updateProgressBar();

                            }
                        } else {
                            // Resume song
                            if (mp != null) {
                                mp.start();
                                // Changing button image to pause button
                                //slider.setProgress(currentPosition+1);
                                Log.d("CurrentPosition2",""+currentPosition);
                                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_pause);
                                //slider.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition()+1);
                                updateProgressBar();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                );

                stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      dialog.dismiss();
                      mp.stop();
                    }
                });
                close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        mp.stop();

                    }
                 });

                dialog.show();
                }

                public void updateProgressBar() {
                    handler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
                }
                private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

                        // Displaying time completed playing
                        cd.setText(""
                                + ut.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

                        // Updating progress bar
                        int progress = (int) (ut.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration,
                                totalDuration));
                        // Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
                        slider.setProgress(progress);

                        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                    }
                };
            });


            holder.timer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                });

            holder.row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Selected: "+ holder.txtName.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return convertView;



        }

    }}
```

Comment: I have missed calling the updation method while playing

Answer (score 0):

don't do anything with the scrollbar,just return true on seekbar touch listener and start mediaplyer on click on your listview item and attach the following listener.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
    {
      @Override
      public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) 
      {
          seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());



           thread=  new Thread(new Runnable() {

                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         if(!Thread.interrupted()){
                             try{
                             while(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                             { 

                                 seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

                                 int millis = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                                  try {
                                      Thread.sleep(100);
                                  } 
                                  catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                             }
                             }
                             catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }
                     }
                     }
             });
           thread.start();

      }
  });
```